# What are these trailing plants with yellow or red flowers and gray leaves called?

Tags: identification, flowers, flowering

I bought this plant from Home Depot a few weeks ago. I threw out the tag and original container it came in and i cannot remember what it was called. Can anyone identify them for me?

[image: trailing plant with red blooms]
[image: trailing plant with yellow blooms]

Answer (score 4):

It looks like purslane ([Portulaca oleracea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portulaca_oleracea)) to me, or else another species of plant in the [Portulaca genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portulaca). Plants in this genus are known as Moss Rose, and it would be normal to find them in a store like The Home Depot. They may also have other colors of flowers.

Comment: Purslane is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it could be some sort of Delosperma, or Ice plant.  Or even some sort of sedum.  Of course you could always go back to HD and see if they still have the plants and find out for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your plant on the top is a Red apple ice plant